# Connect UITableView cell to another UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift, tableview

I am stucked with my project (written in Swift)

I have a UITableView, with a string which provide ten categories in the table.
The thing that I wanna do, is to select one of these categories touching it, and open a secondTableView with other categories. And, when you press on the secondTableView, open the description of that category.

This is my code, this works to have the first UITableView, but when touching nothing happens.
Now I'd like, for example, when I click "Most important places", it open another tableView with, for example, Empire State Building, Statue of Liberty, and when touching Empire State Building, open a Description page.

```
import UIKit

class Categories: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var MainCategories: [String] = ["Most important places", "Monuments", "Nature", "Churches", "Museums", "Streets", "Zones", "Weather", "Events", "Favourites"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.MainCategories.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.MainCategories[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

}
}
```

What can I do? And in the storyboard?
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Very easy, on didselect pass the array to the next tableview, but u need to change datasource a little bit

Comment: Can you help me? What I need to do? I'm new on Xcode programming... Really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So far you have done nothing in didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the second UITableView, it would be easy for you to make use of another viewcontroller which contains the second uitableview and then a third viewcontroller for details.
But if you still want to have 2 uitableviews within same viewcontroller then please follow these steps to achieve the required result.

1. add another tableview and set its datasource and delegate
2. you have to add an if-else condition to differntiate between 2 tablieview in delegate and datasource methods, e.g. numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, didSelectRowAtIndexPath, below is an example of the code if you use 2 uitableviews in one uiviewcontroller. you have to do this if-else for other delegate and datasource mehtos as well.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int {`
    `if tableview == self.tableView {`
  `return self.MainCategories.count`
`}`
    `else if tableView == subCategoryTableView {`
`return self.SubCategories.count`
`}`
`}`

Hope it helps!

Comment: The idea was to create 3 viewControllers, two with a UITableView and one with a description, but I don't know how to link everything.

Comment: it wud be easy for you to use 3 viewcontrollers and connecting them is very easy, add a uinavigationcontroller and make it rootViewController and add segue from 1st to 2nd and another from 2nd to third view controller, and in prepareForSeuge method pass values between viewcontrollers

Comment: Can you please explain me how to connecting them?

Comment: segue are a way in storyboard to connect viewcontrollers

Comment: How to use that? Thanks for the patience :(

Comment: did u add  uinavigationviewcontroller and set it as initial view controller? if so then you must hold option key and drag from uinavigationviewcontroller and drop onto first viewcontroller and select rootView. In the same manner  hold option key and select prototype cell of uitableview in the first viewcontroller and drop it onto second viewcontroller and do it in the same manner for connecting 2nd to 3rd viewcontroller

Comment: Yes, I did it, but which category I need to choose from the black menu from the prototype cell of the first viewcontroller to connect with the second?

Comment: the seuge transition will be push

Comment: Non adaptive selection segue: push deprecated? Is it correct? http://oi60.tinypic.com/wvybzk.jpg

Comment: Fixed, but if I put the navigation controller, instead of the tab bar as initial view controller, when I start the app it shows me only a black screen, instead when I put as initial the tab bar it show me the table. Now that is all connected, if I press a category nothing changes, whatI need to write in the code to let it work and open the SubCategories?

Comment: oh it wud definitely show black screen, as u didnt mention earlier that u used tabbed application, for passing data between view controllers in prepareForSegue method make instance of 2nd view controller (subCategoryVC) and set subCategoryVC.categoryId to the selectedrow index

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to do something. I written, in the firtViewController, the one on the question up there, this:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
          func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if (segue.identifier == "SubCategories") {
                // pass data to next view
            }
    }
    }

But nothing happens to the table, what can I do?

Comment: u jst declare a global variable vairable e.g int catId set this catId in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like int = indexPath.row and in segue pass this to 2nd viewcontroller. suppose u hav a variable named passedCatId in second viewcontroller, in the 1st viewcontroller segue method set this variable using subCategoryViewController.passedCatId = catId   Hope it helps!

Comment: Is a problem for you to write me the code? I really haven't understood how to do that... By the way, thank you for all your answers...

Comment: it wud b difficult to write the whole code here, bt i vil send u a source code tomorrow, if this discussion helped you please vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code, hope this helps

```
import UIKit

class Categories: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
**var selectedCategoryId = -1**
var MainCategories: [String] = ["Most important places", "Monuments", "Nature", "Churches", "Museums", "Streets", "Zones", "Weather", "Events", "Favourites"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.MainCategories.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.MainCategories[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    **selectedCategoryId = indexPath.row**
}
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as YOUR_SECOND_VIEW_CONTROLLER
        vc.catId = selectedCategoryId

}
```

}

Comment: vc.catId = selectedCategoryId gave me this error:

'SubCategories' does not have a member named 'catId'

Comment: u hav to declare this in second viewcontroller as i did in first viewcontroller

Comment: no no, it shud b in first viewcontroller u must declare catId in second viewcontroller.

Comment: Oh, ok, I am sorry. But how can I declare catId in secondViewController? With var it give me errors

Comment: it wud b same like var selectedCategoryId = -1

Comment: Yeah, I have in firstViewController let vc = segue.destinationViewController as SubCategories
        vc.catId = selectedCategoryId
 and in second view controller var selectedCategoryId = -1, but it gave me that error...

Comment: oh no, u hav to declare var selectedCategoryId = -1 in first view controller and catId in secondViewController

Comment: Ok, now it works withour errors and the app starts, but when I click on one of the categories, the subCategories must appere, but nothing happens. I am going to add the secondViewController in a answer, wait a moment.

Comment: Added, did you seen it?

Comment: It's in another answer, here is impossible to show you

Comment: you hav to change this var SubCategories: [String] = ["Most important places", "Monuments", "Nature", "Churches", "Museums", "Streets", "Zones", "Weather", "Events", "Favourites"] to var SubCategories = [["Most important places", "Monuments", "Nature"],[ "Churches", "Museums", "Streets", "Zones"],["Weather", "Events", "Favourites"]]

Comment: cell.textLabel?.text = self.SubCategories[indexPath.row]
'Array<String>' is not convertible to 'String' :(

Comment: and after that in your numberOfRowsInSection delegate method change it like this return subCategories[indexPath.row].count

Comment: do one change, add a new global array as var subCategoryArr : NSArray!

Comment: in viewDidLoad add this line of code subCategoryArr = self.SubCategories[indexPath.row]

Comment: in numberOfRowsInSection change it to return subCategoryArr.count

Comment: in cellforRowAtIndexPath change it like this cell.textLabel?.text = self.SubCategoryArr[indexPath.row]

Comment: Edited the answer with all the code with your last comments, but it give me three errors, written in that answer, check there...

Comment: first undo the last code, back it up till that code which was runnign successfully

Comment: Ok, I am back at the point where it works, but touching the cells nothing happens.

Comment: ok, leave it, now add a global array var subCategoryArr : NSArray! and tel if its ok

Comment: Watch the code above, there is, but when compiling gaves me these three errors... I am getting mad with these codes, I am working on them from days

Comment: adding this single line gives err?

Comment: No I'm sorry, adding var subCategoryArr : NSArray! on the code working is ok